# Checked exception is invalid for this method! Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I tried many references available regarding the same but nothing worked.

I have a method in Kotlin which can throws Checked and unchecked exceptions both(depend on which block in throwing the exception)

```
fun deleteItem(tokens: List<String>, userId: Long) {
        val records = storeRegistry.readItemsByTokens(tokens)
        val missingTokens = tokens.toSet() - records.map { it.token }.toSet()
        if (missingTokens.isNotEmpty()) {
            throw EntityNotFoundException( // checked exception
                "Item with tokens=$missingTokens does not exist."
            )
        }
        transactionManager.executeInTransaction {
            tokens.forEach {
                val success = storeRegistry.deleteItemByToken(it, userId)
                if (!success) {
                    throw InternalException.badRequest( // unchecked exception
                        "Item delete failed: item token=$it"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is called from some other's class method which is in test. and Unit test look like this

```
    @Test
    fun deleteItemShouldThrowIfEntityNotFound() {
        whenever(ItemManager.deleteItemsByTokens(any(), any()))
            .thenAnswer { throw EntityNotFoundException() }
        val deleteRequest = ItemsDeleteRequest.builder()
            .ItemsDeleteParams(
                listOf(
                    ItemDeleteParams.createToken("token1"),
                    ItemDeleteParams.createToken("token2"),
                )
            ).build()
        // act
        try {
            getAfterburner().ignite(
                buildServiceRequest(deleteRequest),
                DEFAULT_TEST_TIMEOUT
            ).join()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            assert(e.cause is EntityNotFoundException)
        }
        verify(ItemManager, times(1))
            .deleteItemsByTokens(listOf("token1", "token2"), 123456L)
    }
```

When I run above test, I got this error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: com.abc.xtz.api.EntityNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3):

Mockito won't throw a checked exception for a function that doesn't have the checked exception as part of its signature. To be able to do this, you need to add the checked exception to the function signature using `@Throws`:

```
@Throws(EntityNotFoundException::class)
fun deleteItem(tokens: List<String>, userId: Long) {
  //...
```

Comment: but in kotlin it's not required to mention exception in function signature. So will it not be weird that I am adding exception in only one signature

Comment: The `@Throws` annotation exists for a reason, for using it with Java code and libraries. But if you want to avoid doing things that are non-standard for pure Kotlin, then you shouldn't throw a checked exception in the first place.